# Error when parsing XML in my Flask (Jinja2) template

Tags: python, xml, api, flask, response

When working with Flask and sending values to the template I get the following **error**:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'best_book'
```

The response from the API call to `https://www.goodreads.com/search.xml` gives me the following XML.

**Data strutcure API response**

```xml
<results>
    <work>
        <original_publication_year type="integer">1985</original_publication_year>
        <average_rating>4.30</average_rating>
        <best_book type="Book">
            <title>Ender’s Game (Ender’s Saga, #1)</title>
            <author>
                <id type="integer">589</id>
                <name>Orson Scott Card</name>
            </author>
        </best_book>
    </work>
</results>
```

Code of my Python code inside of the Flask app where the response is being parsed in **application.py**

```py
works = (xmltodict.parse(response.content, process_namespaces=True)
                     ["GoodreadsResponse"]["search"]["results"])
return render_template("results.html", works=works)
```

**results.html**

```html
{% for work in works %}
<div>
    <p>
        <span>{{work.best_book.title}}</span> -
        <span>{{work.original_publication_year}}</span>
    </p>
    <p>{{work.average_rating}} </p>
    <p>{{work.author.name}} </p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Returns **error**

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'best_book'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a consistency problem when you are parsing a file with only one result. You can correct it like this (also note the `["work"]`) :

```
works = (xmltodict.parse(test, process_namespaces=True)["results"]["work"])
# here we have to trick to make sure we have a list even when there is only one result
if type(works) != list:
    works = [works]
return render_template("results.html", works=works)
```

and in the template `work` is a dict, so :

```
{% for work in works %}
<div>
    <p>
        <span>{{work['best_book']['title']}}</span> -
    </p>
    <p>{{work['average_rating']}} </p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: throws error: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'collections.OrderedDict object' has no attribute 'best_book'`